# Using Tor SOCKS5 proxy with FTP clients (FileZilla)

Tags: windows-7, proxy, ftp, filezilla

I am working on an FTP server that doesn't accept connections from any IP (including my home one). I tried to use FileZilla and FireFTP with Tor (using SOCKS5). They both connect, but they fail to retrieve a directory listing.

I don't have to use Tor: Any free proxy will do, but this is the only one I know of that suppose to work with FTP clients.

Is there any solution for this?

I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You should increase the connection timeout of FileZilla: 
Settings -> Connection -> Timeout

Setting timeout value to something about 180 or 200 should work.

Answer (score 0):

After months of trying almost every solution out there I found out that there are two and only two options, 
1- Using Psiphon - VPN mode (but it is slow)
2- Use a VPN (Some providers are offering a fully functional free trial period)